# Date format problems when passing information from Access to Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, date, ms-access

### just for documentation and future readers, the problem was solved and the answer is in the discussion between me and @varocarbas

My Application is reading a few columns from access data base and joining those columns into an existing datatable. one of the columns in the database has dates, the column is configured as date and time column in the database and in the data column of the datatable. the problem is when i am extrcting it into excel ,**some** of the dates are behaving in the oposite direction (i think the term is "english date"). what that i mean by "behaving", is that excel recognize the monthes as the days and the days as the months, for example a date that should be 11 in september 2015 the excel formula month(11/09/2015) is showing that the month is november and not september.
also, the date values in the access column are from sharepoint list that is also configured as dateandtime.. i have a filling that this behaving maybe belongs to excel(?),
here is the importent parts of my code:

```
' declaring the dateandtime column
  Dim colString As DataColumn = New DataColumn("changed")
  colString.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime")
  UnitedTable.Columns.Add(colString)
```

Storing it from the database:

```
If Not (IsDBNull(UnitedTable.Rows(i).Item("spcall"))) Then
    spcall = UnitedTable.Rows(i).Item("spacll")
    rowNum = Searchbinary(spcall) ' check that spcall exist in Projects table via binary search
    If rowNum > -1 Then
        UnitedTable.Rows(i).Item("somecolumn") = db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(rowNum).Item("PmUserName").ToString
        UnitedTable.Rows(i).Item("somecolumn") = db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(rowNum).Item("OpertionalStatus").ToString
        UnitedTable.Rows(i).Item("somecolumn") = db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(rowNum).Item("CrmCallNum").ToString
        UnitedTable.Rows(i).Item("somecolumn") = db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(rowNum).Item("OperationStart").ToString
        UnitedTable.Rows(i).Item("somecolumn") = db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(rowNum).Item("Approved").ToString
        UnitedTable.Rows(i).Item("somecolumn") = db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(rowNum).Item("GeneralStatus").ToString
        UnitedTable.Rows(i).Item("changed") = db.ReadDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(rowNum).Item("Changed")
    Else
        ' the spcall not exist add it to arraylist
        SpCalls_NotExist.Add(spcall)
        'UnitedTable.Rows(i).Delete()
    End If
```

Then I am populating it to excel with nested loop.

Comment: If you keep the Date/Time type all the way through everything would be fine. The problem is that you are converting to String at some point(s). When doing that, you have to make sure that the string-representation of the date is the right one. For example: `Dim dateString As String = Today.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` rather than `Dim dateString As String = Today.Date.ToString()` (-> which will take whatever date format is applicable in that specific moment).

Comment: so the problem must be when populating it into excel, maybe i need to use ".value" after the worksheet.cells(x,y) = "some string or date"?  just now i found some solution for it by declaring the number format of the excel column like that:  ws.Range("AY:AY").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy;@"

Comment: You should better check the values at each point. For example, your code is converting the information from the database into string without specifying the format for dates and thus the error might be there already. Note that what you are suggesting is just a way to display (as string) the given date in Excel, but if the passed value is wrong (e.g., 5 being the month rather than the day), it would be wrong anyway. You rely on string to create a DateTime variable, which can be displayed in many different (string) formats, but its information (5 being the day or the month) remains unaltered.

Comment: OK, i think i found the problem when the application (in other module) is importing data from share point list into access data base it stores the data temporarily in a string array and than extracting it into the database. thank you for giving me a line of thought!